# Unknown bug in neural network. Is the because matrices are not commutative?

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm having trouble with my first neural network. I simply cannot find the source of the error.

### Problem

Reading the book ["Make your own neural network"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29746976-make-your-own-neural-network) by Tariq Rashid I tried to implement Handwriting recognition using NN which would classify images and determine which digit from 0 to 9 is written down.

After training the NN the tests show that each of the letters have ~99% match, which is obviously wrong.

### Suspicions

In the book the author approaches NN matrices a bit deferent then I have. For example he multiplies input-hidden layer weights with input, which I do other way around by multiplying input with input-hidden weights.

Here is illustration of the way I do matrix multiplication while querying NN (feedforward):

[image: Illustration]

I'm aware that matrices do not posses [commutative property for dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Properties_of_the_matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29) but I it don't notice that I have made an error there.

1. Should I take different approach i.e. transpose all matrices and multiply them in different order?
2. Is there *de facto* standard for dimensions of an input and output matrix i.e. should they be shaped as 1×n or n×1?

If this is wrong approach then it certainly has manifested itself in backpropagation with **gradient descent** used for training.

### Source code

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import scipy.special as scipy
from PIL import Image

class NeuralNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.input_neuron_count = 28*28 # One for each pixel, 28*28 = 784 in total.
        self.hidden_neuron_count = 100 # Arbitraty.
        self.output_neuron_count = 10 # One for each digit from 0 to 9.
        self.learning_rate = 0.1 # Arbitraty.

        # Sampling the weights from a normal probability distribution
        # centered around zero and with standard deviation 
        # that is related to the number of incoming links into a node,
        # 1/√(number of incoming links).
        generate_random_weight_matrix = lambda input_neuron_count, output_neuron_count: ( 
            np.random.normal(0.0,  pow(input_neuron_count, -0.5), (input_neuron_count, output_neuron_count))
        )

        self.input_x_hidden_weights = generate_random_weight_matrix(self.input_neuron_count, self.hidden_neuron_count)
        self.hidden_x_output_weights = generate_random_weight_matrix(self.hidden_neuron_count, self.output_neuron_count)

        self.activation_function = lambda value: scipy.expit(value) # Sigmoid function

    def train(self, input_array, target_array):
        inputs = np.array(input_array, ndmin=2)
        targets = np.array(target_array, ndmin=2)

        hidden_layer_input = np.dot(inputs, self.input_x_hidden_weights)
        hidden_layer_output = self.activation_function(hidden_layer_input)

        output_layer_input = np.dot(hidden_layer_output, self.hidden_x_output_weights)
        output_layer_output = self.activation_function(output_layer_input)

        output_errors = targets - output_layer_output
        self.hidden_x_output_weights += self.learning_rate * np.dot(hidden_layer_output.T, (output_errors * output_layer_output * (1 - output_layer_output)))

        hidden_errors = np.dot(output_errors, self.hidden_x_output_weights.T)
        self.input_x_hidden_weights += self.learning_rate * np.dot(inputs.T, (hidden_errors * hidden_layer_output * (1 - hidden_layer_output)))

    def query(self, input_array):
        inputs = np.array(input_array, ndmin=2)

        hidden_layer_input = np.dot(inputs, self.input_x_hidden_weights)
        hidden_layer_output = self.activation_function(hidden_layer_input)

        output_layer_input = np.dot(hidden_layer_output, self.hidden_x_output_weights)
        output_layer_output = self.activation_function(output_layer_input)

        return output_layer_output
```

### Replication (Training and testing)

The original source of training and testing data is from [The MNIST Database](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). I have used CSV version which I downloaded from the book authors web page [The MNIST Dataset of Handwitten Digits](http://makeyourownneuralnetwork.blogspot.hr/2015/03/the-mnist-dataset-of-handwitten-digits.html).

Here is the code I have used for training and testing so far:

```py
def prepare_data(handwritten_digit_array):
    return ((handwritten_digit_array / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.0001).flatten()

def create_target(digit_target):
    target = np.zeros(10) + 0.01
    target[digit_target] = target[digit_target] + 0.98
    return target

# Training
neural_network = NeuralNetwork()
training_data_file = open('mnist_train.csv', 'r')
training_data = training_data_file.readlines()
training_data_file.close()

for data in training_data:
    handwritten_digit_raw = data.split(',')
    handwritten_digit_array = np.asfarray(handwritten_digit_raw[1:]).reshape((28, 28))
    handwritten_digit_target = int(handwritten_digit_raw[0])
    neural_network.train(prepare_data(handwritten_digit_array), create_target(handwritten_digit_target))

# Testing
test_data_file = open('mnist_test_10.csv', 'r')
test_data = test_data_file.readlines()
test_data_file.close()

for data in test_data:
    handwritten_digit_raw = data.split(',')
    handwritten_digit_array = np.asfarray(handwritten_digit_raw[1:]).reshape((28, 28))
    handwritten_digit_target = int(handwritten_digit_raw[0])
    output = neural_network.query(handwritten_digit_array.flatten())
    print('target', handwritten_digit_target)
    print('output', output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those *facepalm moments*. Neural network has been working as expected all along. The truth is that I have now noticed I've overlooked the test results and **read numbers written in scientific notation incorrectly**.

[image]

Measured on 10000 test data from The MNIST Database this NN has accuracy of 94.01%.